# Configure block takes last argument from the list when iterates

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, dsl

I'm trying to create a set of jobs using jenkins dsl-job-plugin.
I'm using [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) as a workaround for not yet supported plugin, but it appears that parser handles variables in configure block differently and takes only the last item from the list when iterating.

```
def list = ['aaa', 'bbb']
for (item in list) {
    job {
        name = "job${item}"
        configure { project ->
            project / builders << dockerPlugin {
                dockerImageName(item)
            }       
        }
    }       
}
```

Files jobaaa.xml and jobbbb.xml were created. Using [playground tool](https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) can see that xml files have both only 'bbb' item injected:

```
<project>
    <actions></actions>
    <description></description>
    <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
    <properties></properties>
    <scm class='hudson.scm.NullSCM'></scm>
    <canRoam>true</canRoam>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers class='vector'></triggers>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders></builders>
    <publishers></publishers>
    <buildWrappers>
        <EnvInjectPasswordWrapper>
            <injectGlobalPasswords>bbb</injectGlobalPasswords>
        </EnvInjectPasswordWrapper>
    </buildWrappers>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change

```
for (item in list) {
```

To

```
list.each { -> item
```

Or use a variable inside the loop to keep a local copy of item.

Because of the order of evaluation, you will just get the last value of the for loop in your closures (as you have seen)

See: http://blog.freeside.co/2013/03/29/groovy-gotcha-for-loops-and-closure-scope/